# GREP: selecting parts of the paragraphs enclosed by brackets

Tags: adobe-indesign, grep

Please help me select the words within the small brackets, including the brackets themselves so that I can apply formatting to it. Here is a sample text: "This is an apple (red), and that is a banana (yellow). I love mango (green). Do you like radish (white)?

Comment: `\([^)]+\)`? "bracket, everything before a closing bracket, closing bracket"

Comment: BULL'S EYE. That does the magic. Thank you for saving my day. _/\_

Answer (score 1):

The simplest one would be:

```
\(.+?\)
```

`\(` finds the beginning brackets/parenthesis

`.+` finds one or more characters, including spaces

`?` finds the shortest match

`\)` finds the closing brackets/parenthesis